# how do you convert strings to Posixct time format in excel

Tags: excel

I have this field in excel:

```
16JUL15:08:22:13
```

I would like to convert this to POSICct format like this:

```
2015-07-16 08:22:13
```

How would I do this in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":"," ",1),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

The issue is the first `:` between the time and the date.  By removing that it can become a number that can be read as a date.

Answer (score 1):

In an Excel worksheet, you really want to convert that text-that-looks-like-a-date into a real date and then you can do anything you want with how it looks (aka *format*).

Use the native worksheet [REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181) to swap out the colon in the 8<sup>th</sup> position for a space and add a double unary to achieve a true date. Excel's overhead will take care of the rest.

```
=--REPLACE(A2, 8, 1, CHAR(32))
```

Complete the operation by formatting the cell as Custom with a format mask of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

[image: date_to_POSICct]

Comment: I did not want to count, I was being lazy.